# #define with :: (double colon) in identifier for namespaces

Tags: c++

How can I `#define` a type that has a double colon in C++?

For example, I want to include the `std::optional` type from the std library. The code bellow won't work because the compiler cannot parse the double colon in `#define my_namespace::optional`.

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L // C++17
#include <optional>
#define my_namespace::optional std::optional
#else
#include <my_optional.h>
#define my_namespace::optional my_namespace::my_optional
#endif

// Use the optional type
my_namespace::optional<int32_t> some_value;
```

Comment: You simply can't.

Comment: You possibly want a [namespace alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias).

Comment: The answer you’re looking for seems to be different than the duplicate. You want to declare `namespace my_namespace{ using my_optional = std::optional; }`  In general, use macros only when you have to.  (One example: error messages with the filename and line number that crashed the program.)

Comment: You might want to check out [my question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/136350/49895)

Comment: Guys, I think an answer about how to do this without preprocessor macros is more helpful than giving a negative answer about macros?

Comment: @Davislor, good suggestion. I'll unclose.

Answer (score 2):

The answer (thanks to [Davislor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4474419/davislor)):

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L // C++17
#include <optional>
namespace my_namespace
{
    template<class T>
    using optional = std::optional<T>;
}
#else
#include <my_optional.h>
namespace my_namespace
{
    template<class T>
    using optional = my_optional<T>;
}
#endif
```